# program crash due to MessageBoxEx

Tags: c, winapi, text, common-controls, editcontrol

i was trying to extract text from an EDIT control and display it in a MessageBox in win32, the code compiles and runs but whenever i click the button to do the task, the program stops working and crashes, i tried to trace it on my own and somehow figured out that the MessageBoxEx made the crash, here is the fragment of the code,

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDB_BTN1:
                    {
                        LPTSTR str
                        Edit_GetText(hEdit1,str,255);
                        MessageBoxEx(hwnd,str,"INPUT",MB_ICONINFORMATION,0);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: This code does not compile. It's always best to post the exact code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first failure occurs at `Edit_GetText`. You pass it an uninitialized pointer. You then pass on that same uninitialized pointer to `MessageBoxEx`.

Change your code to allocate a buffer:

```
TCHAR str[255];
Edit_GetText(hEdit1, str, 255);
MessageBoxEx(hwnd, str, _T("INPUT"), MB_ICONINFORMATION, 0);
```

If you had checked the return value of `Edit_GetText` for errors you would have learnt that something was wrong there. Always check return values for errors with the Windows API.

Comment: Then check the return value of the call to `Edit_GetText`. The only other failure mode available now is for `hEdit1` to be an invalid window handle, or for that window to have no text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate a buffer to receive the text:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDB_BTN1:
        {
            TCHAR szBuffer[255];
            Edit_GetText(hEdit1,szBuffer,255);
            MessageBoxEx(hwnd,szBuffer,"INPUT",MB_ICONINFORMATION,0);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```